# How to list all non-environment variables in bash?

Tags: bash, variable, echo

I'd like to `echo` all non-environment variables (all self-declared variables), in Bash 3.2.52.

This command to print all variables gave me output I can't understand that seems to me to conflict with the `set -x && clear -r` mode I already work in.

```
diff -U 1 <(set -o posix ; set |cut -d= -f1) <(
    exec bash -ic 'set -o posix ; set' | cut -d= -f1)  |
        grep '^[-][^-]'                                |
        cut -d- -f2                                    |
        grep -vE '^(COLUMNS|HISTFILESIZE|HISTSIZE|LINES|PIPESTATUS)$'
```

I need an `echo` or `printf` (or any other "simpler") operation to have such list.
If possible in this version of Bash, how can this be achieved?

Comment: An unreliable solution (which is why I'm not posting it as an answer): `grep -vxF -f <( declare -x -p ) <( declare -p )`. It's unreliable whenever there are variables containing newlines (which there almost always are). Also does not work with the stock `bash` on macOS as the lines in the output of `declare -p` does not start with `declare` (while the ones from `declare -x -p` do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU Parallel includes `env_parallel`. Part of `env_parallel` lists all variables for the supported shells.

For `bash` this code is:

```
_names_of_VARIABLES() {
    compgen -A variable
}
_bodies_of_VARIABLES() {
    typeset -p "$@"
}
```

So given all variables we need to figure out which ones are set by the user. We *can* do that by hardcoding all variables set by a given version of `bash`, but that would not be very future proof, because `bash` may set more variables in future versions (Is `$BASH_MYVAR` set by the user or by a future version of `bash`?).

So instead `env_parallel` asks you to define a clean environment, and run `env_parallel --session` in that. This will set `$PARALLEL_IGNORED_NAMES` by listing the names defined before (using the code above).

When later run in an environment where the user has set variables, it is easy to take the difference between the clean environment and the current environment.

`env_parallel --session` makes it possible to define a clean environment for every session, but if you prefer to have a reference environment that can be used across sessions, simply save the list of variables to a file. So:

```
# In clean envronment
compgen -A variable > ~/.clean-env-vars

# In environment with user defined vars
compgen -A variable | grep -Fxvf ~/.clean-env-vars
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# In clean envronment
compgen -A variable > ~/.clean-env-vars

myvar=4
yourvar=3

# In environment with user defined vars
compgen -A variable | grep -Fxvf ~/.clean-env-vars

# This prints:
# myvar
# yourvar
# PIPESTATUS (which is set when running a pipe)
```

Comment: I am not sure I have enough knowledge to understand the answer at the moment, but in a test WSL machine, when I ran the last command, I didn't get the values of two variables I declared: `x=1` and `y=2`. Instead, I Got: + compgen -A variable
+ grep --color=auto -Fxvf /root/.clean-env-vars

Comment: @JohnDoea I tested the example on WSL, and I get the output shown. Not sure why you get a different output. It sounds as if you `bash` is configured in a special way.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to best come up with a "clean" environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357464/how-to-start-a-shell-without-any-user-configuration for advice there

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`

```
pre () {
    set -o posix;set > /tmp/tmp-original-envs
}

post () {
    set -o posix;set > /tmp/tmp-new-envs
    diff /tmp/tmp-original-envs /tmp/tmp-new-envs | grep -v BASH_LINENO | grep -v FUNCNAME | grep '>'
}
```

Then run `pre` before your modifications and `post` afterward

Example:

```
[localhost]$ pre
[localhost]$ test=new
[localhost]$ post
> test=new
[localhost]$
```

Comment: Hello. I don't understand what you meant by *modifications*. Thanks anyway,

Comment: @JohnDoea what i meant is that the `pre` command is ran on a clean environment to record its state (without non-environment variables), then you can run your application and or declaration of your new variables, afterward the `post` command find out the new non-environment variable that were declared by comparing the current state to the old one... right now there is no native feature for this purpose, most answer to this question do compare 2 states of bash env variables to keep the solution simple.

Comment: Other advanced solutions that i am thinking of to this question, could be patching bash to add the feature, or develop a library that would use LD_PRELOAD to catch the changes while it occur... but those require some development work to be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Kludgy, bash-only solution:

```
(setn(){
   set | sed '/^{/,/^}/d;/=/!d;/^BASH[A-Z_]*=\|^PPID=\|^SHLVL=\|^PIPESTATUS=\|^HISTSIZE=\|^HISTFILESIZE=\|^_[a-z_]*=/d' | sort
}
export -f setn
comm -23 <(setn) <("$BASH" -ic setn))
```

You may have to also filter out other variables via the `sed` (or make the `BASH..` pattern more strict). The `/_[a-z_]*=/` is supposed to exclude variables defined by the programmable completion like `_backup_glob` or `_xspecs`; that too could be made more strict.

`bash` will print the values of variables which contain funny characters in the `$'...'` format, so you'll have to handle that:

```
foo='
bar
baz
'
...
foo=$'\nbar\nbaz\n'
```

`bash` will not create shell variables from envvars whose *names* contain newlines, so there's no way to break this hack by such a trick.

Comment: Seems not to work if user sets `BASHMYVAR=1` (which is not a `bash` variable).

Comment: Already noticed in "you may want to .. make the `BASH` pattern more strict".

Comment: Hello, thank you; I have defined two variables: `x=1` and `y=2`. After I ran the above command and got a huge output, not just a list of variables...

Comment: I guess you have the programmable completion turned on; that's defining a lot of functions (and some variables), and when in posix mode, `set` in bash will also print the source of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Depending on your needs, one simple solution could be:**

1. Save current variables before your modifications with `set > tmp` or `set > /tmp/current`
2. Do you modifications/run your application
3. Extract what was modified with `diff -u <(cat tmp) <(set)` or

```
diff -u <(cat tmp) <(set) | tail -n +3 | grep -v PIPESTATUS | grep -v "_=" | grep -E "^\+"
```

Where:

`tail -n +3`: remove the first unneeded line of diff command

`grep -v PIPESTATUS | grep -v "_="`: remove unneeded variables

`grep -E "^\+"`: display only required/needed changes

**Alternative:**

```
diff -u <(set -o posix; set) <(bash -lc 'set -o posix; set') | grep -E "^\+"
```

**Note:**

In your script note that `exec` replace completely the the process it is launched from this may interfere with what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hello, thank you; I have defined two variables: `x=1` and `y=2`. After I ran the above command and got a huge output, not just a list of variables...

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to echo all self-declared variables (all non-environment variables)

This is a task for `comm`, as to me:

```
comm -23 <( set | cut -d= -f1 | sort ) <( env | cut -d= -f1 | sort )
```

`-23` means `comm` should omit printing columns 2 and 3.

3rd is such entries that are found in both lists and 2nd is entries that are only in `env`'s post-processed output.

Or, IOW, *show only unique entries that were in 1st list*.

P. S. Since some entries can be found in both lists at once (check them with `comm -12 …`), you *could* also want to include them into resulting set. It means you shouldn't use `-3` in that case and lines from 3rd column would be shown shifted when printed.

Comment: Seems to break if there are functions set (I get a lot of lines with { and }).

Comment: It wasn't my intent to handle "functions" case but rather to show how differences between 2 lists can be isolated in a handy way.

Comment: To get just variables invoke `set` in POSIX mode: `set -o posix ; set ; set +o posix`. You'll also want to grep for an `=` before you `cut` - so something like `comm -23 <( set -o posix; set|grep =| cut -d= -f1 | sort ) <( env | cut -d= -f1 | sort )` ... maybe

Comment: Thanks for adding, that might be helpful.

Comment: Hello, thank you; I have defined two variables: `x=1` and `y=2`. After I ran the above command and got a huge output, not just a list of variables...

Comment: Ah, seems I got it. What you're looking for isn't comparison to env. variables but user-defined variables instead to ones of other types. Of course `env` won't help you at this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had some problems with [the solution that uses `compgen -A variable`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547581/108618). It might be because of `set -x` you mentioned in the question body, I don't know.

---

Without `compgen` now. Let's start with [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/546664/108618#comment1014369_546664). It says:

> ```
> grep -vxF -f <( declare -x -p ) <( declare -p )
> ```

I partially improve it to

```
grep -vxF -f <( declare -x -p | grep -o '[^ =]*=') <( declare -p | grep -o '[^ =]*=')
```

There are few problems now:

1. A variable that contains `=` in its content will make the above code report false positives. Example:

   ```
   foo='123
   bar=baz
   =xyz'
   ```

   Run the code. It will print (among others) `foo=`, `bar=` and `=`. To fix this we should test each line if such variable really exists.
2. Or we can get duplicates:

   ```
   foo='123
   aaa foo=456
   bar=baz
   bar=qux'
   ```

   To fix this we can use `sort -u`. I prefer `LC_COLLATE=POSIX sort -u` to get lowercase variables at the end.
3. The above `foo`, if exported, can "mask" legitimate (not exported) `bar`. Example:

   ```
   export foo
   bar=999
   ```

   Now the code will not print `bar=`. To fix this we should not exclude basing on "global" `declare -x -p`. For each variable we should separately check if it's not exported. This step makes the preliminary `grep -vxF` unnecessary.

So this:

```
declare -p | grep -o '[^ =]*=' | LC_COLLATE=POSIX sort -u \
   | while IFS='=' read -r v ; do
      [ -v "$v" ] \
      && bash -c "[ ! -v '$v' ]" \
      && printf '%s\n' "$v"
done
```

Note I do not strictly check if a variable is exported. I check if it is set in a child `bash`. There are variables specific to interactive shell that will be reported, you may want to filter them out manually. Or you can run `bash -ic …`; but multiple times, so it will be even slower.

Since we have a reliable(?) way to get a list of all variables without false positives, we can go back to the original idea of `grep -vxF` and only run a child `bash` once. The following snippet works quite well with `bash -i`. In my case the only variables to manually filter out are `COLUMNS` and `LINES`.

```
( set +x
function _get_vars {
declare -p | grep -o '[^ =]*=' | LC_COLLATE=POSIX sort -u \
   | while IFS='=' read -r v ; do
      [ -v "$v" ] \
      && printf '%s\n' "$v"
   done
}
export -f _get_vars

_get_vars | grep -vxF -f <( bash -ic '_get_vars' ) \
| grep -vE '^(COLUMNS|LINES)$' )
```

I deliberately use `set +x` for the subshell just in case; the subshell is also useful to keep the function "local" (it will not be available in your current shell). You may prefer a non-interactive child bash and more filtering. Adjust this to your needs.

---

Maybe, just maybe `set +x` in the right place will make the `compgen` approach work for you. How about this?

```
( set +x
compgen -A variable | grep -vxF -f <( bash -ic 'compgen -A variable' ) \
| grep -vE '^(COLUMNS|LINES)$' )
```

---

<sup>Disclaimer: not tested in Bash 3.2.52; tested in 4.4.12.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution may get you along the road to listing all non-environment variables. It definitely handles variables defined like `ITEM=$'VALUE\nSTRANGE=QUARK'` and `ALSO=$'VALUE\ndeclare -r LANG=fake'`, i.e. with an embedded newline.

```
for item in $(declare -p | awk '$2 !~ /[aAx]/ && $3 ~ /.=/ {print substr($3,1,match($3,"=")-1)}')
do
    if [[ -n "$item" ]] && ! { env -0 | grep -q $'\0'"${item}="; }
    then
        printf ">> %s = %s <<\n" "$item" "${!item}"
        # printf "%s\n" "$item"
    fi
done
```

You can tweak the `printf` statement to print just the variable names, add them to an array, or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

my bash version is 3.2.57

I use `set +o posix` , this change the behavior to  display contens for each variables in one line

to filter i use `sort| uniq -c` , and keep lines with a value  of 1  l

```
bash-3.2$ bar=" foobar= "
bash-3.2$ foo="0
> 1
> 2 "
```

> now i i have 2 variables *foo* *bar*

```
bash-3.2$ A=$(  (  ( set +o posix ; set |cut -d= -f1 ) ; 
                   ( bash -ic 'set +o posix ; set |cut -d= -f1' )  
                ) | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *1 //p;d' | 
               grep -vE '^(COLUMNS|HISTFILESIZE|HISTSIZE|LINES|PIPESTATUS|BASH_EXECUTION_STRING)$' )
bash-3.2$ echo $A
bar foo
```